# How to get around OS X Lion Server SMB "safe save"?

Tags: mac-osx-server, file-permissions, server-message-block, osx-lion

First, there is this problem:

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4149

Which says that anything copied to os x server via smb will be "safe saved" and essentially chmod to 600.  This is extremely annoying and counterproductive to having a share server...

I did what the article said, but nothing has changed.  It is *very* vague about how to actually set the ACL permissions, but I think I did that via Server.app -> hardware -> storage -> edit permissions.  I added (in addition to other things):

Guests - Read & Write
Others - Read & Write

Actually every entry is read and write, but despite this...it is **still** chmod to 600 when I try to copy a file via SMB.  Where else should I look to solve this madness?

Alternatively, how can I get rid of this crappy SMB and put back the original SMB?  I tried SMBUp but it just fails to start the service every time...

Comment: I experienced a very similar problem with OS X clients accessing a Windows-based SMB server.  The problem was caused by having different permissions in the root of the share (where "safe save" files are created) than the sub-folders (where users were saving their files).  Our "hack" solution was to deny permission to the safe save folder, which seemed to cause the clients to stop using safe save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for anyone else with this problem...I think the easiest answer is to just give up and install Samba3 from MacPorts.  I did that and had the server working correctly in about 15 minutes, instead of the hours I spent pounding my head against the wall fighting against something that is confusing and counter productive.

Comment: I have the exact same problem... I can't figure it out... Any more news? Using OS X Server 2.2.1 on 10.8.2

Comment: @unmircea Not that I know of, other than with Mavericks Apple has redone their SMB stack again.

Comment: True, however it did not work very well. Yosemite seems to have finally fixed all issues, but only time will tell.